# Query not inserting empty data as empty into DB (MAMP)

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have read in other websites that local servers' php.ini is configured in different ways. However, I believe that by filling out the rest of the columns manually, it should be able to insert the data. It isn't even showing me any alert. This is my code.

```
      $datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                 "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                 "password" => $encriptar,
                 "rol" => $_POST["nuevoRol"]);

  $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($datos);
  if ($respuesta == 'ok') {
    echo '<script>
      swal({
        type: "success",
        title: "Se ha creado un nuevo usuario",
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
      }).then(function(result){
        if(result.value){
          window.location = "usuarios";
        }
      });
    </script>';
  } else {
    echo '<script>alert("asdf");</script>';
  }
} else {
  echo '<script>
    swal({
      type: "error",
      title: "Por favor llena los campos correctamente",
      showConfirmButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
    }).then(function(result){
      if(result.value){
        window.location = "usuarios";
      }
    });
  </script>';
}
```

}
}

```
  static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($datos){
$statement = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, usuario, password, rol, estado, ultimo_login)
                                            VALUES (, :nombre, :usuario, :password, :rol, :estado, :ultimo_login)");
$statement->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":rol", $datos["rol"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":estado", '0', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(":ultimo_login", '0', PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($statement->execute()) {
  return "ok";
} else {
  return "error";
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: your question is `Query not inserting empty data as empty into DB (MAMP)` but you make no reference to the data being inserted and how it looks in the DB - what do you mean not inserting empty as empty?

Comment: My point is: As I am not adding the fields "estado" and "ultimo_login" with the POST variable, I am trying to insert them manually with '0' but I am not able to.

Comment: what's the data type for the column?

Comment: Added a screenshot for the table structure.

Comment: try this: `$statement->bindParam(":estado", 0, PDO::PARAM_STR);` - the datatype of the col is INT - strings won't be accepted, as for the other one - it's a DateTime field - 0 won't work here either

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, no insertion in the database occurred.

Comment: `VALUES (,` that's a typo.

Comment: Fixed it, but still no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try with the use of `->execute()`

remove the `bindParam`'s and change to this:

```
$statement->execute(array(
    ':nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
    ':usuario' => $datos['usuario'],
    ':password' => $datos['password'],
    ':rol' => $datos['rol'],
    ':estado' => 0
));
```

I think you're use of `PDO::PARAM_STR` on non-strings is one reason it's failing. Also I notice `ultimo_login` has a default value in the database, so remove from your insert sql and remove from the execute array and it will automatically insert the datetime stamp correctly.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Do you have ajax knowledge? I'm also having trouble when attempting to edit these values in the application.

Comment: @OscarParedez bit extensive but post a separate question and I'll keep an eye out :)

Comment: Got skype? I can only post every 90 minutes :P

Comment: @OscarParedez (un) fortunately not, I don't touch Microsoft products with a ten foot pole

Comment: Done :) Question posted!